# How to validate pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In the admin panel, I have something called `Group` that an admin can make a group of users so my scheme is:

##### `groups` table contains:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | group1 |

##### `group_user` table contains:

| id | group_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

My logic is: if a `user` belongs to a `group`, that `user` *cannot* be added again to the same `group`:

In update, when I add a `user` that already exists in `group`, it added it again:

```php
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'sometimes|nullable|string',
        'user_ids' => 'sometimes|array',
    ]);

    $group = Group::findOrFail($id);

    $group->update($request->only('name'));

    if ($ids = $request->user_ids) {
        $group->users()->attach($ids);
    }

    return $this->apiRespone(null, 'group updated successfully', null, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if user already is in the group before attaching to it:

```php
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'sometimes|nullable|string',
        'user_ids' => 'sometimes|array',
    ]);

    $group = Group::findOrFail($id);

    $group->update($request->only('name'));

    foreach($request->user_ids as $user_id) {
        if (!$group->users()->where('id', $user_id)->exists()) {
            $group->users()->attach($user_id);
        }
    }

    return $this->apiRespone(null, 'group updated successfully', null, 200);
}
```

**Update:** 
To get the list of already existing members, apply this in your loop logic:

```php
    $existingUsers = [];
    foreach($request->user_ids as $user_id) {
        if (!$group->users()->where('id', $user_id)->exists()) {
            $group->users()->attach($user_id);
        } else {
            $existingUsers[] = $user_id;
        }
    }

    // now you can use $existingUsers
```

Comment: What if I need to message the admin that this user already exists like "Moshen is already in this group"

Comment: @user16390519 Then you need an `else` block to the `if` inside the `foreach`, and inside you push the already existing members to an `array` and return it.

Comment: @user16390519 See the answer, I updated it with your requirement. Also vote up the answer, thank you.